# Why does music keep playing during videos?

Tags: macbook-pro, music

Why does music play when I'm watching videos?

Sorry re lack of detail.  I have a Mac Air. I use Firefox.

It first happened maybe a year ago when my son sent a little home video taken on iphone. There was this slow dirge-like repetitive music playing in the background--loudly, too, so that I couldn't hear the voices on the video. When I lower the volume, the background music also decreases, along with sound on the video.

That continued for several months and happened for videos from the web as well. It then stopped for a couple of months and today it's back.  Watching SNL iconic episodes on Yahoo.

I should add that this same tune plays continuously, whether a video is playing or not. So I keep the volume muted when just using the web.

Comment: What app or website are the videos playing in, and how (what app or website) are you listening to music through?

Comment: your question is like: "why did the chicken cross the road"! without details no one can answer it. For example if you have music playing from a web site, then go and watch a video on another, both will play till you stop one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the added detail, Linda. Music playing for no reason is absolutely not normal. I would make an appointment with the Genius Bar if you have one within driving distance.

Answer (score 1):

So, music always plays when you have web browser open, regardless of any videos?

Maybe.. check if there are tabs open, try to close them one after other if you would find if one of those has background music. Chrome and some other browsers might show an icon indicating if a tab is playing music.